# What are some important real life examples of multi objective optimization problem with box constraints to work on?

Tags: optimization, multi-objective-optimization, test-instances

In the search of some of the important cutting edge many objective optimization problems to be solved using non-dominated sorting genetic algorithm (NSGA) and its variants.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How did you get interested in this area? Did your advisor suggest this? Do you have even a single example you can share with us? I suppose any multi-objective problem which has bound (a.k.a. box) constraints. And perhaps no other constraints?